# How to write a media query in CSS?

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to write different styles in following cases

**Device width greater than device height**

```
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .bg img {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Device height greater than device width**

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .bg img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

**Orientation** doesn't work perfectly in some stages on resizing the browser.

How to write correct CSS?

Is it possible to do so with CSS?

EDIT :

I am attaching image how it looks on resizing the browser[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work in some stages on resizing the browser"? Orientation doesn't mean width is lower than height or vice versa, the orientation is calculated, like explained [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained). I'm not sure, if you can emulate the orientation with a desktop browser.

Comment: @martinCzerwi: "Orientation doesn't mean width is lower than height or vice versa" On desktop browsers, at least Firefox, it does.

Comment: @martinCzerwi There is background image, on resizing I am giving it width `100%` and height `auto` to get image in aspect ratio when width greater than height. and vice versa. The problem is on resizing the browser the image will get full height in some stages.

Comment: I have added an image, how it shows in browser on resizing.

Answer (score 4):

You have access to the browser's [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29) with these media query features: `aspect-ratio | min-aspect-ratio | max-aspect-ratio`. For more info, check out [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) on MDN.

Portrait has an aspect ratio greater than `1:1` and landscape is less. To verify, I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/JPpzb/embedded/result/) that changes color when you switch from "landscape" to "portrait".

Try this:

```
/* Landscape (i.e. wide viewport) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
    .bg img {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Portrait (i.e. narrow viewport) */
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
    .bg img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

**Update:** The image is part of the flow of the document, and won't fill the viewport unless the body also fills the viewport with `body {height: 100%;}`, as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/JPpzb/1/).

Try `img {position: absolute;}` to pull the image out of the flow, so it's dimensions aren't constrained by the body's size. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/JPpzb/3/).

Comment: No, still it shows like the image I have attached to question.

Comment: I see. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/JPpzb/3/) more what you're going for?

Comment: I have already given position absolute. The style  `{    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1; }`

Comment: It would help to see all the markup so we can give you a solution to your complete scenario. Could you create a little JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you were having was that you were relying on the text "orientation:landscape" which is not recognised by browsers. Use the code below which check the height and width of a device to calculate its orientation. Credit to css-tricks.com who can really help with media queries, here is an example of the most common uses of media queries.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Source http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need but I was using:

```
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3)' href='css/tall.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3)' href='css/wide.css' />
```

The only problem was, when I hit 768 x 1024 it displayed correctly, but when I went to 1024 x 768, I got a blank page.  I was using a simple css display assignment like:

```
display:none;
```

to turn the div on or off, which works but my question is how can you make a continuos flow without that break? at 1024 x 768

I am using this right now:

```
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (orientation:portrait)' href='css/tall.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (orientation:landscape)' href='css/wide.css' />
```

I would like to use max-aspect-ratio and what not, because that gives me more control over when change happens.  I mean I can't put 1.333 ratio and 1.334 bummer...

--NEW UPDATE

```
         <!-- tall -->
         <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-aspect-ratio:4/3) and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1023px)' href='css/tall.css'/>
         <!-- tall -->
         <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-aspect-ratio:4/3) and (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:9999px)' href='css/tall.css'/>
         <!-- wide -->
         <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-aspect-ratio:4/3)' href='css/wide.css'/>
```

I guess I fixed my problem by doing the above code, which is disappointing.  But it works so far, I am just going to have to test for almost every screen to make sure higher resolutions that are EXACTLY 4:3 by the Query "terms" still show.  I tried 2048 x 1536 iPad3 Retina and that shows up, don't know why 1024 x 768 fails... but is working with the fix above.

----UPDATE 2 (I hate to be a pain but)
This seems to be the cleanest solution for aspect-ratio:4/3 :

```
         <!-- tall 1.33301 -->
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-aspect-ratio:4095/3072)' href='css/tall.css'/>
         <!-- wide 1.33333 -->
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-aspect-ratio:4096/3072)' href='css/wide.css'/>
```