# width and max-width attributes of image

Tags: css

Could anyone tell me the relationship between `width` and `max-width` (such as which override which in terms of pixel, percentage, etc)?

How can I use them if I want to:

- Auto scale an image when I resize the window and stop scaling when the image reach its original size?
- Keep a fixed size until I resize window to certain small size and then start to auto resize

Comment: `width` is the width of the element and `max-width` is the maximum width of the element can be. Which part of this is confusing you? There is also a `min-width` which is the minimum width of the element can be

Comment: `max-width` overrides `width`. Do you even need to use `width` in your code?

Comment: @Huangism The part confuses me is if I use percentage as value of max-width, what that percentage based on?

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, but when I use  tried width: 1000px; max-width:100%; for an image, the image will auto scale until it reach 1000px and then it will stop scaling, in this case, the max-width can not override the width, could you help me with how to understand this?

Comment: @Huangism  So for an img tag under body tag(whose width is 100%), what the 100% max-width means? I tried it, it can auto scale until it reach the real size of the image, why it can not keep scaling  based on body(its container width)?

Comment: @Kuan I think you are kind of miss-using max-width. If you want the image to keep scaling then remove max-width and just use `width: 100%` Use `max-width` to limit the image getting too big. Usually people use `max-width` with a finite number or unit, if you set % then I think it is the % of the current element. So when you set 100% it won't expand anymore because it has reached 100% of the original size which you set with `width`

Answer (score 1):

Width is the actual width of the element whereas max-width is the highest the width attribute can be. Max-width is just the limit for the width attribute.

If you want to have an image resize based on the size of the window, you can simply use a percentage for the width of the image. So 100% width would make the image as wide as the container it is within. You can then set the max-width to the width of the file so that it will never distort or stretch.

If you want to keep a fixed size until you resize the window to a certain size, you can use a media query to set the width of the element at a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

From the spec:

> **[10.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) Minimum and maximum widths: ['min-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width) and ['max-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width)**
>
> These two properties allow authors to constrain content widths to a
>   certain range.
>
> The following algorithm describes how the two properties influence the
>   [used value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#computed-value) of the ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) property:
>
> 1. The tentative used width is calculated (without ['min-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width) and ['max-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width)) following the rules under ["Calculating widths
>      and margins"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) above.
> 2. If the tentative used width is greater than ['max-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width), the rules [above](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) are applied again, but this time using the computed
>      value of ['max-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) as the computed value for ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width).
> 3. If the resulting width is smaller than ['min-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width), the rules [above](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) are applied again, but this time using the value of
>      ['min-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width) as the computed value for ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width).
>
> However, for replaced elements with an intrinsic ratio and both
>   ['width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) and ['height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) specified as 'auto', the algorithm is
>   as follows:
>
> Select from the table the resolved height and width values for the
>   appropriate constraint violation. Take the max-width and max-height as
>   max(min, max) so that min ≤ max holds true. In this table w and h
>   stand for the results of the width and height computations ignoring
>   the ['min-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width), ['min-height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height), ['max-width'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) and
>   ['max-height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-height) properties. Normally these are the intrinsic width
>   and height, but they may not be in the case of replaced elements with
>   intrinsic ratios.
>
> ```
> Constraint Violation                   | Resolved Width                   | Resolved Height
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> none                                   | w                                | h
> w > max-width                          | max-width                        | max(max-width * h/w, min-height)
> w < min-width                          | min-width                        | min(min-width * h/w, max-height)
> h > max-height                         | max(max-height * w/h, min-width) | max-height
> h < min-height                         | min(min-height * w/h, max-width) | min-height
> (w > max-width) and (h > max-height),  | max-width                        | max(min-height, max-width * h/w)
>     where (max-width/w ≤ max-height/h) |                                  |
> (w > max-width) and (h > max-height),  | max(min-width, max-height * w/h) | max-height
>     where (max-width/w > max-height/h) |                                  |
> (w < min-width) and (h < min-height),  | min(max-width, min-height * w/h) | min-height
>     where (min-width/w ≤ min-height/h) |                                  |
> (w < min-width) and (h < min-height),  | min-width                        | min(max-height, min-width * h/w)
>     where (min-width/w > min-height/h) |                                  |
> (w < min-width) and (h > max-height)   | min-width                        | max-height
> (w > max-width) and (h < min-height)   | max-width                        | min-height
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition from mozilla:

The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of a given element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

With max-width you set the max size to width.

When you resize a image, the width will that was set with "width" or "max-width".

See this example below:

```
/* image width will be always 500px */
img{
  max-width:500px;
}
/* image width will be 100% of parent*/
img{
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
   float:left;
   display:block;
   background: #00f;
}
```

here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmxw7j4p/

You can use media queries either: [How to write a media query in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474562/how-to-write-a-media-query-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

> Auto scale an image when I resize the window and stop scaling when the
>   image reach its original size?

```js
var w = 100;

$('#bigger').click(function() {
  w+=25;
  if (w>100)
    w= 100;
  $('div').css('width', w+'%');
});

$('#smaller').click(function() {
  w-=25;
  if(w<0)
    w=0;
  $('div').css('width', w+'%');
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    transition: 2s;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px green solid;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="smaller">reduce container width</button>
<button id="bigger">enlarge container width</button>
<div>
    <img alt="This is an image!" />
</div>
```

---

> Keep a fixed size until I resize window to certain small size and then
>   start to auto resize

```css
    img {
        width: 300px;
    }
    @media (max-width:768px) {
        img {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<img alt="That's another image!" />
```